# Height problems with childrens elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, responsive-images

I got a problem with the height of the childrens elements of `.contenedor-elementos-generales`
I don't know what to do to fix it.

My main html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    <title>Descontrol</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="item-grilla contenedor-carta">
            <img src="." alt="" id="imgCarta" class="img-carta">
            <div class="contenedor-consola-carta">
                <span class="consola-carta" id="textoConsolaCarta">Descripción carta: Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet
                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit obcaecati voluptatem eius quibusdam facilis dolores
                    suscipit id a explicabo laborum.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-grilla contenedor-consola-personaje">
            <span class="consola-personaje" id="textoConsolaPersonaje">Consola: Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, vero nesciunt? Repellendus quos ipsam fugit?</span>
        </div>

        <div class="item-grilla contenedor-botones-juego">
            <div class="boton-juego boton-levantarCarta" id="btnLevantarCarta">
                <span>LEVANTAR CARTA</span>
            </div>
            <div class="boton-juego boton-atacar" id="btnAtacar">
                <span>ATACAR</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-grilla encabezado-elementos-generales">
            <div class="encabezado-personaje">AVATAR</div>
            <div class="encabezado-atributo">ATRIBUTO</div>
            <div class="encabezado-estado">ESTADO</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-grilla contenedor-elementos-generales">
            <div class="elemento-general contenedor-personaje">
                <img src="img/vida.png" alt="" id="imgPersonaje" class="img-personaje">
            </div>
            <div class="elemento-general contenedor-atributo">
                <div class="atributo">
                    <img src="img/ataque.png" alt="" class="img-atributo">
                    <span class="text-atributo">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="atributo">
                    <img src="img/esquiva.png" alt="" class="img-atributo">
                    <span class="text-atributo">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="atributo">
                    <img src="img/velocidad.png" alt="" class="img-atributo">
                    <span class="text-atributo">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="atributo">
                    <img src="img/vida.png" alt="" class="img-atributo">
                    <span class="text-atributo">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="atributo">
                    <img src="img/vida.png" alt="" class="img-atributo">
                    <span class="text-atributo">0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="elemento-general contenedor-estado">
                <img src="img/vida.png" alt="" class="img-estado" id="imgEstado">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My css file:

```css
* {
    all: initial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Titillium Web;
}

.layout {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    outline: 1.5px solid #000;
}

.contenedor-carta {
    grid-column: 1/10;
    grid-row: 1/12;
    background: #000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.img-carta {
    height: calc((6/11)*100%);
}

.contenedor-consola-carta {
    height: calc((5/11)*100%);
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.consola-carta {
    padding: 0 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contenedor-consola-personaje {
    grid-column: 1/10;
    grid-row: 12/15;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.consola-personaje {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.contenedor-botones-juego {
    grid-column: 1/10;
    grid-row: 15/16;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.boton-juego {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.boton-juego.boton-levantarCarta {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.encabezado-elementos-generales {
    grid-column: 1/10;
    grid-row: 16/17;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.encabezado-personaje,
.encabezado-atributo,
.encabezado-estado {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.encabezado-personaje {
    grid-column: 1/ span 2;
}

.encabezado-atributo {
    grid-column: 3 / span 5;
}

.encabezado-estado {
    grid-column: 8 / span 2;
}

.encabezado-elementos-generales * {
    text-align: center;
}

.contenedor-elementos-generales {
    grid-column: 1/10;
    grid-row: 17/-1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    height: 100%;
}

.contenedor-personaje {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.contenedor-atributo {
    grid-column: 3/8;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    background: #000;
}

.atributo {
    margin: 0 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

.img-atributo {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}

.text-atributo {
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.contenedor-estado {
    grid-column: 8/-1;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .layout {
        width: 60vw;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .layout {
        width: 40vw;
    }
}
```

The `.layout` element is suppost to be a grid 9x18 that matches the dimension of the any window, which does it, the problem is the height of the element `.contenedor-personaje`, `contenedor-atributo` and `.contenedor-estado`.
If you found another mistake or have a suggestion, please be free to tell I'm still a begginer in web desing.
Navegator: Chrome
OS: Ubuntu 20.04